# Delete button in uitableview cell is not working properly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am showing comments in UItableView and created delete button in Cell..When I delete any comment It will delete. and I used `[Tableview reloadData]`, but It always delete last cell from table and when I checked the deleted comment next time it is fine.. Why table view always delete last cell.. My code is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i",indexPath.row];

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


       //delete button in uitableview cell ================================

         deleteBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

         deleteBtn.frame = CGRectMake(270, 10, 20, 20);

          //[deleteBtn setTitle:@"delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

          [deleteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deletefb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

          [deleteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(delete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    deleteBtn.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

           [cell.contentView addSubview:deleteBtn];

            }

            return cell;

    }
```

Delete method is

```
- (void )delete:(id)sender {


    UIButton *myDeleteButton = (UIButton *)sender ;




    //delete method of comment

    NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];

    [variables setObject:@"delete" forKey:@"method"];


    [fbGraph doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Facebook *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:myDeleteButton.tag]postId]] withPostVars:variables];


     //load tableview 
    [self responseMethod];  //method to load comments
    //show alert
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Deleted"
                                                   message:@"" delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil ];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];







}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving `deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row;` outside of the `if (cell == nil)` condition.

In your current setup, when you reuse a cell rather then instantiate a new one the `tag` will reference the old `indexPath.row` rather than that of the new one. This may well be why you're seeing cells deleted other than the one expected.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    // Do you other stuff here         
}
deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
return cell;
```

Also, you don't seem to grasp the concept of reusing table cells. The identifier should be a constant string applied to all cells, not a dynamic one as you have setup here. For instance

```
NSString *identifier = @"someUniqueValue";
```

Comment: I used deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row outside But still it is deleting last row

Comment: NSString *identifier = @"someUniqueValue";
I used this also.. But my table cell's value move to first cell and interchange with each other

Comment: Are you sure it's actually *deleting* the last row, or because you are re-querying a datasource that now has one less result the tableview is just displaying one less record? This would give the illusion of deleting the last row when infact it's not. It's a little difficult to determine exactly what's happening as you don't seem to be removing cells in a *typical* manner.

Comment: actually when I delete any cell. It always disappear last cell. I don't know it is deleting or what?

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper I'm not sure what you mean about your cell's value moving to the first cell as no where in the code above do you set the cell's value. If you are setting it but left it out, then it also needs to go outside the `if (cell == nil)` condition. The only things that should reside inside that condition are those common to all cells. Things specific to individual cells (*such as values, tags etc*) must go outside the condition.

Comment: I have created label in if(cell == nil) { } and If my table array has large value and scroll table down the values appeared in last cell will also appears in first cell..after scrolling,.

Comment: please tell me the correct way..where should I create labels?

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper But you don't seem to be actually *deleting* any rows, instead you are deleting a comment from FaceBook and then re-querying the comments and displaying them; therefore there will always be one less than prior to the delete, and it will seem it's the last row that has been deleted when in-fact it's not.

Comment: hey Thanks a lot.. I create all the labels and button outside if(cell== nil) And It is working fine...:)

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper The most efficient way is to create the label inside `if (cell == nil)` **but make sure** you set its value outside

Comment: ok means I should alloc it in if condition and assign it outside .Thanks

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper Yes. Create and position any views inside, assign any values outside.

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper Inside. If you create views outside and add them to the cell, you'll be doing this each time the cell is reused meaning overtime cells will build up a huge number of unused subviews which will take up memory and eventually slow down your app. If you create and add them inside, you only ever do this once when the cell is instantiated. Then, every time you reuse the cell you just set the values instead.